# Multicolumns in one table instead of three separate tables

Tags: latex

I want table in overleaf with three main columns in one table. I used muticolumn, but instead of one table with three columns it comes as three tables. It comes like this:
[image]

Here is the code for it. I am trying to remove the spaces between columns and make it look like one table. Any help appreciated

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\center
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\caption{ Model of Dataset I Tested on Dataset III}
\label{my-label7}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{14}{|c|}{Model Based Approach } \\
\hline
Hosts &  A & B & D & G &  H &  I &  J  &  L &  M &  N &  P & Q & R \\ \hline
DR   & 1 & 0.85 & 0.6 & 1   & 1  & 1 & 1 & 1  & 1  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\ 
\hline
FPR & 0.04        &   0   & 0    & 0    & 0   & 0 & 0 &0   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 
0 \\ \hline

\end{tabular} 
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Instance Based Approach} \\
\hline
C  &  E &  F &  K &  O \\ \hline
1  & 0.79 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Average} \\
\hline
All   \\ \hline
\textbf{0.95}  \\ \hline
\textbf{0.03}  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

The table is set as three different tables because it is set using three separate `tabular`s. Below I've combined them, but also used [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs for a less line-based approach.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
  \caption{Model of Dataset I Tested on Dataset III}
  \begin{tabular}{ *{20}{l} }
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{13}{c}{Model Based Approach} &
      \multicolumn{5}{c}{\makecell[b]{Instance Based \\ Approach}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{Average} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-14}
      \cmidrule(lr){15-19}
      \cmidrule(lr){20-20}
    Hosts & A & B & D & G & H & I & J & L & M & N & P & Q & R &
      C & E & F & K & O &
      All \\
    DR    & 1 & 0.85 & 0.6 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
      1 & 0.79 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
      \textbf{0.95} \\
    FPR   & 0.04 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &
      0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 &
      \textbf{0.03} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```